# Which is the best database to store JSON data to perform analytics

Tags: database, analytics

I would like to perform analytics on the requst and response information to know the user pulse and serve them in a better way.

In-order to accomplish this I started storing the both request and response information in json format to cassandra as we are using both mysql and cassandra in our project and  the size of content is not more than 20 attributes(Key value pairs) where the response attributes have some paragraphs of text in response.

Looking for some thoughts on where to store (which Database) this JSON info and what kind of analytics tool we can use.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to have more information regarding your config. According to my understanding, since you're running Cassandra the data might be in NoSQL.

The choice of selecting the Database depends of few parameters like modularity of data fields, speed of data transfer and business requirements.

Analytics of data is correlated with complexity of data and statistical significance of columns. If you need in memory running calculations, you can use SAS. For advanced statistical analysis use R or Python based analytics. Using Python for analysis is best bet as it gives you ability to develop complex or simpler systems.

If you are starting entirely from clean slate. My advise is work backwards from business needs to table design.

1. First understand the problem which analytics is trying to address.
2. Decide the relevance of data columns.
3. Identify whether you want your Database should be ready with 2 joins or 3 or more joins.
4. Using previously mentioned parameters, decide NoSQL, PostGres or SQL. If you are dealing with Big Data, use NoSQL, XML & avoid Oracle.

**Links:**

[Database that support JSON](https://www.quackit.com/json/tutorial/list_of_json_databases.cfm)